# Down/Up Timestamp Calculation

Tags: awk

New to code so please be gentle. I have searched to the point of headaches and have found close to what I am trying to do but not quite there yet.

I have a log file that shows connection status. My goal is to have one line that will calculate the time difference between the DOWN and UP times.

```
cat file.txt | grep device | grep status_change | awk {time column} | awk 'present Up time next to Down time'
```

So now my times displays went from:

```
10:30:00
10:31:00
```

to

```
10:30:00 10:31:00
```

Is it possible to add to the end of my line, code to calculate the time difference?

```
cat file.txt | grep device | grep status_change | awk {time column} | awk 'present Up time next to Down time' | awk '{print $3=$2-$1}'

1:00
```

Something like that. If not I will keep banging away at a bash script.

Again I am new to this and will go ahead and apologized for the crude examples. I also am grateful for any help.

Comment: Please add sample input and your desired output for that sample input to your question.

Comment: You do not need multiple greps plus multiple awks to do anything. Show us concise, testable sample input and expected output so we can try to help you. You really need a date as well as a time to do this accurately as the difference between 1am and 3am is 2 hours on a normal day but 1 hour or 3 hours on DST transition days, for example.

Comment: ++ for date, since the down/up time range may contain 12am. You may end up with negative downtime. On second thought, that might be good :)

Answer (score 0):

Result in seconds:

```
echo 10:30:00 10:31:00|awk '{dt=strftime("%Y %m %d ");gsub(":"," ",$1);gsub(":"," ",$2);print mktime(dt $2)-mktime(dt $1);}'
# => 60
```

Apend the awk part to your command cluster would do.
You can further format the time difference to what you want.
You can check awk's time functions [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Time-Functions.html).
PS: It's for GNU awk.